# DigitalOcean - cap staging deploy error on precompiling assets

Tags: deployment, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano, rake-task

When I run `cap staging deploy:check` it succeeds. When I run `cap staging deploy` it succeeds until `deploy:assets:precompile` at which I get this error:

```
 01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile
 01 rake aborted!
 01 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "links" does not exist
 01 LINE 1: SELECT "links".* FROM "links"
```

After googling, I believe the problem is that it is trying to create the relations before creating the tables. I have since tried many solutions including placing `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` in application.rb but none of them work.

I desperately need help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the asset:precompile task boots up the full Rails environment. Do you have any initializers or something that use **Link** model?

Dirty workaround:

ssh to the staging server, go to **:deploy_path** you've set in capistrano's config and then in last release folder. After that manually run **RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake db:migrate**.

Comment: I don't have any initializers using my Link model. I do have this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52729750/rails-5-create-vanity-route-for-each-instance-of-model <- going on in my routes.rb. Could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: I also have no app files/folders on the server yet since that all gets created in the `cap staging deploy` action so I can't cd to :deploy_path and run that command. Should I go ahead and clone my repository over to the server and then do that? Will that cause any issues with capistrano? This is my first time deploying like this so capistrano and all that is completely new to me

Comment: The routes.rb thing was the problem. I commented out the lines and `cap staging deploy` ran fine. Thank you @vladimir-dimitrov for helping me rethink through some of this!